# Cannot connect to MySQL using a PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I am trying to connect to MySQL DB and display data in an array. I have AMPPS installed and the DB is loaded into phpMyAdmin. When I try to open this PHP code the web page appears blank and gives me a 404 error.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("maps")or die("could not find db check spelling kimo sabi");
error_reporting(5);
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'locations'");
while($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
{$data[] = $row;}
print($data); die();
?>
```

I am using Netbeans IDE. I have tried both to run the file and to manually open it. The name of the file is default NewemptyPHP

Comment: If you're getting a 404, the problem does not lie with php. Double check that the file is where you think it is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However I have created several new files in the same project and they all open without a problem. I can also higlight the file and click run file as and it still will not open

Comment: There should not be any space in file name try something else as file.php etc

Comment: Make sure apache or nginx or whatever is allowed to at least read the file.

Comment: Aside from the question: Don't use mysql_ as it's deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong [**identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for your table, which are quotes.

```
("SELECT * FROM 'locations'")
                ^         ^
```

Either remove them:

```
("SELECT * FROM locations")
```

or wrap the table name in backticks:

```
("SELECT * FROM `locations`")
```

Use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to identify errors.

---

***Sidenote:***

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**`mysqli_` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're safer*.